# Is it possible to authenticate a web API using CAS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

=== SETUP ===

ASP.net - Visual Studio - MVC & Web API - Entity Framework

Currently, the application is calling a third party database and displaying those results that I have selected by creating a new controller with scaffolding for these results. I've attempted to add the [authorize] filter and have followed the following article, but my website is not requiring you to be signed into CAS. I would like only those registered users to be allowed to view the website.

=== GOAL ===

It seems like the only way you can use CAS is with forms, however I am interested in knowing if it is possible to set this up were you are able to require authentication when trying to access a web API. Would it be possible that if a user accesses the URL they have to log in to CAS to view results?

=== RESOURCES ===

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/.Net+Cas+Client
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/ASP.NET+Forms+Authentication

Comment: Hello, were you able to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't use the .Net CAS client, but I believe there is one specifically for MVC which works. I use the following code for CAS SSO:

**AuthController.cs**

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private readonly string _casHost = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CasHost"];
    private readonly string _casXMLNS = "http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas";

    private readonly IBannerIdentityService _bannerIdentityService;

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public AuthController(IBannerIdentityService bannerIdentityService)
    {
        _bannerIdentityService = bannerIdentityService;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Auth/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    //
    // GET: /Auth/Login
    public ActionResult Login(string ticket, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        // Make sure CasHost is specified in web.config
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_casHost))
            Logger.Fatal("Could not find CasHost in web.config. Please specify this value for authentication.");

        string strService = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

        // First time through there is no ticket=, so redirect to CAS login
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ticket))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReturnUrl))
            {
                Session["ReturnUrl"] = ReturnUrl;
            }

            string strRedirect = _casHost + "login?" + "service=" + strService;

            Logger.Debug("Initializing handshake with CAS");
            Logger.DebugFormat("Redirecting to: {0}", strRedirect);

            return Redirect(strRedirect);
        }

        // Second time (back from CAS) there is a ticket= to validate
        string strValidateUrl = _casHost + "serviceValidate?" + "ticket=" + ticket + "&" + "service=" + strService;

        Logger.DebugFormat("Validating ticket from CAS at: {0}", strValidateUrl);

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new WebClient().OpenRead(strValidateUrl));
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        XNamespace xmlns = _casXMLNS;

        Logger.DebugFormat("CAS Response: {0}", xdoc.ToString());
        Logger.Debug("Parsing XML response from CAS");

        var element = (from serviceResponse in xdoc.Elements(xmlns + "serviceResponse")
                        from authenticationSuccess in serviceResponse.Elements(xmlns + "authenticationSuccess")
                        from user in authenticationSuccess.Elements(xmlns + "user")
                        select user).FirstOrDefault();

        string strNetId = String.Empty;

        if (element != null)
            strNetId = element.Value;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strNetId))
        {
            Logger.DebugFormat("User '{0}' was validated successfully", strNetId);
            Logger.DebugFormat("Loading user data for '{0}'", strNetId);

            // Get banner data
            var bannerUser = _bannerIdentityService.GetBannerIdentityByNetId(strNetId);

            // Make sure banner user isnt null
            if (bannerUser == null)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(String.Format("Could not found any banner records for the Net ID ({0}).", strNetId));

            Logger.DebugFormat("Logging in user '{0}' as a system user.", strNetId);

            Response.Cookies.Add(GetFormsAuthenticationCookie(bannerUser));
        }
        else
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (Session["ReturnUrl"] != null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = Session["ReturnUrl"].ToString();
            Session["ReturnUrl"] = null;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl) && Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            ReturnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
        }
    }

    private HttpCookie GetFormsAuthenticationCookie(BannerIdentity identity)
    {
        Logger.DebugFormat("Building FormsAuthentication Cookie for user: '{0}'", identity.NetId.Value);

        UserPrincipalPoco pocoModel = new UserPrincipalPoco();
        pocoModel.BannerIdentity = identity;

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string userData = serializer.Serialize(pocoModel);

        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            identity.NetId.Value,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
            false,
            userData);

        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        return new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
    }
}
```

and the Web.Config looks something like:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="CasHost" value="https://auth.myschool.edu/cas/" />
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Auth/Login" timeout="30" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

There's a lot of extra code in there as I like to pull user data from a database and attach it to the forms authentication cookie, but hopefully you can see how we are getting the username from CAS.

This will work on any controller annotated with the [Authorize] attribute, even WebAPI.